# incorrect column spacing when defining data checkbox datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox, datatable

I have a datatable in which uses row grouping and a checkbox plugin from [gyrocode](http://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/). For any of the selected rows, I wish to return the following data in this format:

SFA Id : Goal ID : SC : Obj ID

I'm able to return the data correctly, how even I get extra spacing in the column with the checkbox.

In my data function, the following returns the correct spacing:

```
// This one works 
var myData1 = row[1] + ":" + row[4];
return myData1;
```

[image]

When I add the other columns I wish to retrieve, extra spacing is added as such:

```
// The string below will NOT render spacing correctly 
var myData2 = row[1] + ":" + row[4] + ":" + row[3] + ":" + row[6];
return myData2;
```

[image]

Here is my [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccakn5870/hk7ec27r/1/) with the full code. How can I achieve the spacing in `myData1` when I wish to return the data in `myData2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like DataTables is setting the size of the column based on the data length you return. Try this and see if it works.

```
data: function(row, type, val, meta) {

  // we don't care what we display because it's replaced by a checkbox
  // so return something small
  if (type === 'display') {
    return '';
  }

  // This one works 
  var myData1 = row[1] + ":" + row[4];
  // The string below will NOT render spacing correctly 
  var myData2 = row[1] + ":" + row[4] + ":" + row[3] + ":" + row[6];
  // The string below will NOT render spacing correctly 
  var myData3 = row[1] + ":" + row[4] + ":" + row[6];
  return myData2;
},
```